# @PreAuthorize with hasPermission() executes code twice

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop, pre-authentication

I want to use @PreAuthorize Spring annotation to controll access in my application.

The problem is, that I have a lot of conditions depends not on the request parameters, but on the database entities.

**Overview:**

I have an `Route` entity, that has `User owner` field. You can remove the `Route` only if you are an owner.

I have written my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/route/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'RouteRemove')")
  public String removeRoute(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap model) {

  Route route = routeBO.getById(id);

  if(null == route)
    return "forward:/errors/404";

  // ... remove route here.
  // routeBO.remove(id);
}
```

My `RouteRemove` permission is defined as:

```
@Component
public class RouteRemovePermission implements Permission {

    @Autowired
    private RouteBO routeBO;

    @Override
    public boolean isAllowed(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject) {
        if(!(targetDomainObject instanceof Integer))
            return false;

        Route route = routeBO.getById((Integer) targetDomainObject);

        if(route == null)
            return false;

        User user = AthenticationUtil.getUser();

        return null != user && user.equals(route.getOwner());
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have to evaluate `routeBO.getById()` twice.

**Question:**

is it possible to evaluate this code only once?

*Of course i have tried:*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/route/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String removeRoute(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap model) {

Route route = routeBO.getById(id);

if(null == route)
  return "forward:/errors/404";

return removeRoute(route, model);
}

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'RouteRemove')")
public String removeRoute(Route id, ModelMap model) {

    return "route/display";
}
```

but there no invocation of permission method before `removeRoute(Route id, ModelMap model)`. Maybe I have incorrect configuration?

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
  <sec:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</sec:global-method-security>
```

security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="pl.wsiadamy.common.security.BasePermissionEvaluator">
  <beans:constructor-arg index="0">
        <beans:map key-type="java.lang.String"
             value-type="pl.wsiadamy.common.security.Permission">
            <beans:entry key="RouteView" value-ref="routeViewPermission" />
            <beans:entry key="RouteRemove" value-ref="routeRemovePermission" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="routeViewPermission" class="pl.wsiadamy.common.security.permission.RouteViewPermission" />
<beans:bean id="routeRemovePermission" class="pl.wsiadamy.common.security.permission.RouteRemovePermission" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you break out your security-annotated removeRoute method to a separate service class, like:

```
@Service
public class RouteService {
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#route, 'RouteRemove')")
    public void removeRoute(Route route) {
        // remove route here
    }
}
```

Then you use it in your web controller:

```
@Autowired RouteService routeService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/route/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String removeRoute(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap model) {
    Route route = routeBO.getById(id);
    if(null == route)
        return "forward:/errors/404";
    routeService.removeRoute(route);
    return "route/display";
}
```